# How to get all solr field names except for multivalued fields?

Tags: solr

I'm new to solr and I'm trying to query for field names excluding fields with multiValued=true.

So far I have

`select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet`

which returns all the fields.

Is there a way to modify the query to check if a field is multivalued?

Comment: You can retrieve information about all the defined fields through the Schema API: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/schema-api.html#list-fields - the response will contain a `multiValued` field set to `true` if the field is defined as multivalued. You can't do it as part of the query as far as I know.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks! Checking the `multiValued` field worked just fine for my use case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve information about all the defined fields [through the Schema API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/schema-api.html#list-fields). The response will contain a multiValued field set to true if the field is defined as multivalued:

v1 API:

```
http://localhost:8983/techproducts/schema/fields
```

v2 API:

```
http://localhost:8983/api/collections/techproducts/schema/fields
```

```json
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "name": "_version_",
            "stored": true,
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "indexed": true,
            "multiValued": true,  <----
            "name": "cat",
            "stored": true,
            "type": "string"
        },
    ],
    "responseHeader": {
        "QTime": 1,
        "status": 0
    }
}
```